# Determine "a" and "b" so that the function is continuous with all values of x

Tags: limits, functions

I´ve been stuck on this assignment for a while. The question is:

> The function h is defined piecewise as follows:
>
> $$h(x)=\begin{cases}
>   -2x+a, & x<-1 \\
>   x^2+b, & -1 \le x < 1\\
>   2x+a,  & 1 \le x
> \end{cases}$$
> How should the parameters "a" and "b" be chosen, so that the function h is continuous with all the values of x

That is the entire question and all the information I am given.

After looking at different methods for determining a and b in a piecewise function like this, the thing that trips me up is that the first expression (-2x+a) contains "a" which I should determine somehow.

Every method and guide I've found has "a" or "b" first come up in the second expression and the first expression only contains x and numbers.

I know that I need to determine the limit value for -1 and 1 like this.

$$\lim_{x\to -1-}(-2x+a)=\lim_{x\to -1+}(x^2+b)$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 1-}(x^2+b)=\lim_{x\to 1+}(2x+a)$$

I´m just stuck on trying to figure out how can I mathematically determine "a" and "b".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a definition of continuity available, something like right limit should equal left limit or something? Based on that, you will need to find the left and right limits of $h(x)$, at both $1$ and $-1$ : can you do that? In short : try to narrow down your difficulty in solving this question a little more. Thank you for using MathJax.

Comment: Where might the function be discontinuous?  Can you select $a$ and $b$ to avoid the potential problem?  There will be more than one correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your editing. +1 to your question, and I hope you receive a good answer. Having said that, the answer to the question "$\lim_{x \to -1-} (-2x+a)$" can be found, but it will depend on $a$. Similarly, $\lim_{x \to -1+} (x^2+b)$ is something that can be found in terms of $b$. Then, the equations you have will give you equations that relate $a$ and $b$ : which you can solve to find $a,b$. So treat $a,b$ like constants : for example, $\lim_{x \to -1+} a = a$, because $a$ is a constant. Now try the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Simply notice that

$$\lim_{x\to -1-}(-2x+a)=2+a, \quad \lim_{x\to -1+}(x^2+b)=1+b,\quad \lim_{x\to 1+}(2x+a)=2+a$$

Now solve for $a$ and $b$. The solutions are not unique: $a$ and $b$ can be any pair of real numbers with $2+a=1+b$.

Comment: This helped a lot. I used $$2+a=1+b$$ to solve "a" and "b" like so: $$a=b-1$$ and $$b=a+1$$ I kept pondering this for a while until I realized that "a" is just whatever "b" is -1 and "b" is just whatever "a" is +1.  
It checks out.

Comment: @Talar: That is correct. In the subject of linear algebra, one studies systematical such equations and their solutions.